# Advanced Eloquent/Laravel question. Can't make a MorphPivot Class with a morphMany relation work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have this class. Which has a `morphedByMany` relationship

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrdenDeElaboracion extends Model
{
    // ... Stuff goes here


    /**
     * Get all of the model variants that are assigned this production order.
     */
    public function variantes()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Variante', 'elaborable')
            ->withPivot(['cantidad', 'informacion_adicional', 'informacion_adicional_fabricacion', 'informacion_adicional_instalacion'])
            ->using('App\Elaborable');
    }
}
```

But now I want that other class `App\Elaborable` to have relationship with this one `App\Estatus` so every "variante (product variant)" on the "elaborable (items with the ability to be elaborated)" table could have a "estatus (status)"

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class Elaborable extends MorphPivot
{
    // ... more stuff here

    /**
     * The relations to automatically populate to the model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['estatus'];

    /**
     * Get the status records associated with the order.
     */
    public function estatus()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Estatus', 'modelo');
    }
}
```

But this does not work for me I don't know why.
The `MorphPivot` class extends from `Model` so I can't figure out what am I doing wrong

**Update: Code Example**

```php
Route::get('/get_test', function () {
    $orden_de_elaboracion = OrdenDeElaboracion::findOrFail(1);
    return $orden_de_elaboracion->variantes->map(function ($variante) {
        $newEstatus = new Estatus([]);
        $variante->estatus()->save($newEstatus);
        return $newEstatus->id;
    });
});
```

With that I get this. Like if the relationship wasn't defined.

[image]

I don't know if this has something to do -> https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17770

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work for me"? Does the relationship itself or `$with`  not work?

Comment: relationship itself

Comment: How are you using it? Is there an error?

Comment: It says the relation does not exist. I don't know if this has something to do -> https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17770